# Not able to do locate subfolder of a php application

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

how can i view and edit this file [www.example.com/about.php?service=training,its](http://www.example.com/about.php?service=training,its) hosted on google compute engine, i can access  about.php from htdocs ,my focus is to edit some text on the training page.
I'm unable to view file/folder for 'service=training' with ls -la, ls -al
using this vi https://www.example.com/about.php?service=training
when i tried saving the file,it tells me can't open the file for writing

"https://www.example.com/about.php?service=training" E212: Can't open fi
le for writing

Comment: What do you mean by "locate subfolder"? Viewing and editing your source code should happen on your local machine

Comment: You should accept the answer below instead of adding an unnecessary edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

`?service=training` is not a file or a folder, it's a query parameter. The file you're dealing with is `about.php`, and that file contains a script which calculates what output to display based on what the value of `service` is.

How this script does that is impossible to tell without seeing the file. This content can be stored in a variable in `about.php`, or it can be saved in an external file, or it can be stored in a database. But the function that decides what content will be displayed on screen is somewhere in `about.php`.

Comment: Thanks @olafmoriarty, will need support in viewing this file